# cost of cloud SQL to BigQuery transfer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I have a Cloud SQL database (as PostreSQL) and I would like to transfer a copy to BigQuery. This represents 1 Tb of data (cloud SQL storage used), over 100 tables.

I would like to estimate the cost of this one-off, large data transfer. When I read the GCP documentation for BigQuery and Cloud SQL pricing, I get the impression that this is free: BigQuery imports are free and Cloud SQL network egress to Intra-continental "other Google Products" are free. Am I correct?

Also, I would like to confirm whether this is feasible (data size not too large) via BigQuery's "federated queries", for example looping through tables to select all and insert each one into BigQuery. Or any other more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Federated Queries:**

When querying an external data source from BigQuery, you are charged for the number of bytes read by the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  EXTERNAL_QUERY(
    'connection_id',
    '''SELECT * FROM customers AS c ORDER BY c.customer_id'''
  );
```

This query costs all the size of the customers table from Cloud SQL. It's affordable for small tables. For 1 TB it will cost $5.

**Loading into BigQuery from Cloud Storage**

Loading data is free. But this means you need to engineer a solution to export the data from your Cloud SQL, place the file CSV, JSON on Cloud Storage, then import into BigQuery.

**Conclusion**:

Either you pay the transfer costs $5 per TB, or you weigh the work hours and calculate your time taken to write the export/import script. If costs more the hourly rate to write the script, then choose the federated query read and write to a temporary table.

Comment: $5 in the cheapest location of BigQuery. It's sometime more, but greatly affordable!

Comment: For completeness, GCS would also incur storage costs but we can round it to zero if we delete it as cleanup after the BigQuery import.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if both BigQuery and Cloud SQL are in the same region, this transfer action should be free. If I were you, I would use a storage bucket in the same region as your Cloud SQL as an intermediate place to store your data. Exporting a Cloud SQL instance is free as long as the data does not leave the GCP network and is stored in the same region.

Note that if you are doing a serverless export from your Cloud SQL instances, Google will in the future charge you some money. I got all this information from the export/offload pricing [page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/pricing#export-offload).

> Serverless export - No charge until February 1, 2021, thereafter
> $0.01/GB of the instance storage capacity.

The easiest / most efficient solution would be to create a CSV export to a storage bucket ([source](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#csv)). And then import that CSV into BigQuery ([source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#limitations)). I think especially the export could take a while since it is 1TB, but other than this, the size should not be a problem.